# Javascript xml empty tag error

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I'm trying to parse a xml from tht thetvdb.com, the problem is that some tv series don't have a name in english so the tags look like this:
http://www.thetvdb.com/api/92DBDD8C9816A59C/series/256618/

you only have `</SeriesName>` and the `<SeriesName>` is missing.

when I try to print the names like this:
console.log("name: " + serieNameT[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

my code stops in series like that and the error is 'TypeError'.

how can I pass this elements without problems?

thanks!

Comment: I see `<SeriesName/>`, not `</SeriesName>` in the file. Self closing tags are valid in XML. It looks like your problem is that this empty node does not have a `childNodes` attribute or it is empty and hence you cannot access the first element. It should not be difficult to test whether `serieNameT[0].childNodes[0]` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the childNodes exist before referencing them.

```
if (serieNameT[0].childNodes.length > 0)
    name = serieNameT[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
else
    name = "Default series name when empty tag";
```